# Open and read MS Word document over FTP, in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-office

I need to know a way to open and read the word document from the FTP using this two namespace.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
```

I know that how to write code to open and read WORD document from the local machine, but I need to write a code where I could connect to FTP and open and read WORD document from FTP using above namespaces

How Can I do ? Help

Comment: So are you asking how to download the file [FtpWebRequest]? once you have done that, save it to disk and use interop to open it in word ...

Comment: I know the way to write code to download file but I dont want to do like this. I just want to read Document from Ftp.

Comment: You must download it, you can't make work interact with it when its sitting on a remote FTP server somewhere

Comment: ok So first I must need to download document After that only it could be possible to read document.

Comment: If you download the file and save it as xxx.doc you can do with it whatever you wish

Comment: you can use the OpenXML sdk to open a Word document IO Stream. Are you trying extract data out of a Word document ( without displaying the document )  ?

Comment: yes I am trying to extract data out of a word document.